# Lorentz Transformations - time of 2 separated clocks in a moving frame

Tags: special-relativity

In using Lorentz transformations, I have 2 frames, Frame $S$ and Frame $S$ prime moving with velocity $v$ w.r.t. frame $S$. There are 2 synchronized clocks in $S$ Prime, one at the origin and another unit $1$ distance from the $S$ prime origin. If I calculate the time $t$ prime for the clock at the origin of $S$ Prime and $1$ unit away using the Lorentz transformation, for a given instant, $t$, in the $S$ frame, the values seem to be different.

Even though the time in $S$ prime will be delayed w.r.t. the $S$ frame, but I thought all clocks in $S$ prime will read the same time? The underlying concept that I am looking to clarify is this : 2 clocks in S prime might be out of sync for S frame. But for S prime, for a given instant, how can 2 clocks read 2 times. I know I am missing something just not able to see it.

This is not a homework or a calculation question as it was closed marking it in that category. I think it is a conceptual question which other might have.

I am attaching a picture for reference.

[image]

Comment: Writing *S prime* instead of *S'* kinda defeats the purpose in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider two events that are simultaneous in one of the frames, they will not be simultaneous in the other, so two clocks that appear synchronised in one frame will be out of synch in the other.

Comment: Right. 2 clocks in S prime might be out of sync for S frame. But for S prime, for a given instant, how can 2 clocks read 2 times. i know I am missing something just not able to see it.

Comment: @user31058 :  Have you never owned two clocks that were out of synch in your (and their) frame?

Comment: @user31058 because a given instant in S frame is a flat slice through time in S frame, but a sloping slice through time in S prime. The slice that is 5pm, say, everywhere in frame S, is a sloping plane of time in S prime. The clocks in frame S prime are synchronised with each other, but you are considering them at different  instants all along the sloping slice.